# How to use ob_start on a string?

Tags: php

I have a project where I am using OB_START to gather output from a PHP file. The problem is that sometimes I need the contents of the PHP file 20 - 30 times in 1 call.

I'd like to do something like get_file_contents({file}) then use that string for the OB_START() call. However, all the examples I've seen use an include() call to get the script each time.

Is there a way to load the script one time but use it several times in OB_START() calls?

```
ob_start();
include "file.php";
$output = ob_get_clean();
```

What I would like to do:

```
$script = get_file_contents(file);
$output = '';
begin loop;
ob_start();
{somehow make $script execute as code}
$output .= ob_get_clean();
end loop;
```

Comment: I can't figure out what you're asking. There's no string in an `ob_start()` call.  You can use `ob_get_contents()` and store that in a string, and reuse it as much as you want.

Comment: it would help if you actually showed the structure of your script, and explained what you want it to do. Your question as currently written is much too vague.

Comment: You're basically describing a templating engine. You can find lots of them out there.

Comment: Why not use a function? (Which you can define in the included script file.) And why use the `ob`-functions when you can use a variable to collect data, use/store it and reset it?

Comment: THis is meant to build the HTML for a page of forum messages. So each time through, the data to be processed by the PHP will be different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `include` over-and-over again.

```
$file = "SomeScript.php"
$output = '';
begin loop;
ob_start();
include $file
$output .= ob_get_clean();
end loop;
```

If you're dead-set on doing it the way you're describing, you can do the following, but it's weird:

```
$script = get_file_contents(file);
$output = '';
begin loop;
ob_start();
eval($script);
$output .= ob_get_clean();
end loop;
```

In my opinion, a much better solution would be to make the script a function that outputs it's results instead of printing them.  So let's say you put the "script" into a function call foo(), Then you could do this:

```
$file = "SomeScript.php"
include $file
$output = '';
begin loop;
$output .= foo();
end loop;
```

But if you cannot change the contents of the script, then my first two examples should work for you.

Comment: It seems that doing an include over and over would use a lot of resources. This is for filling-in an HTML template for messages in a project I'm working on. So it needs to print the final HTML after the PHP inserts.

Comment: I'm not sure why it "seems" that way.  I gave you the answer to your question.  If you're worried about architecture, then you need to scrap this whole idea anyways.  But if you want to do what you say you want to do, then this is the way to do it.  I also provided two alternatives to the `include()`

Comment: Why do you consider your second solution above weird? IT looks like what I am looking for. Doesn't it make more sense to load the script once rather than 20 or 30 times?

Comment: I honestly don't think either one makes too much sense, in an ideal world.  The only reason to use either approach is if you cannot alter the contents of the PHP file.  If you can alter it, then the third approach is the best one.  The reason eval() is not the ideal solution is because: 1) a lot of hosting providers disable it (which they do because of #2), 2) It can be a security risk (it is not a risk the way you are proposing to do it, however), and 3) Dynamic PHP evaluation is slow.  I think include() would be faster because after the first include it would be opcode cached (I assume).

Comment: However, having said that, if you are able to use eval(), and you are not able to edit the underlying PHP file, then I do not think eval() is a worse solution than the include(), necessarily.  If the eval() is working well for you then I think it's fine in this case.

Comment: I did a little reading now since you mentioned caching. It looks like include_once() should cache the file so further IO calls are not necessary.

Comment: Only problem is if you call include_once on the same file more than once, subsequent calls are completely ignored.  It literally will only include a file *once*.

Comment: On subsequent calls I believe they are not ignored, but, rather, you get the same file data you got the first time without going back to the filesystem. Isn't this correct?

Comment: from http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php  "if the code from a file has already been included, it will not be included again. As the name suggests, it will be included just once" So no, it will not get the same data.  It will just be ignored.  Use `include` instead... it's opcode will be cached so subsequent calls will be fast.

Comment: Thanks. I read the same thing but some of the subsequent discussion gave me the wrong idea. I did indeed end up using 'include'.